# Pre-loading fonts

Tags: css, webfonts

Do i need to use both rel="preload" and font-display="swap". Since `rel="preload"` prefetches the required font, is it necessary to add `font-display` attribute too?

```
<link rel="preload stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Magra&display=swap" as="font">
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the intended result.

With `font-display: swap`, text is immediately rendered using the fallback typeface specified in your font stack while the request is made for your font. The fallback is whatever system font comes next in your font stack as listed in your `font-family` property.

Once the font is downloaded, it will be swapped in for the fallback.

This is just one option and you don't *need* to use it. For example, the immediate rendering of text when using `font-display: swap` creates a flash of unstyled text (FOUT) for the user and possible shifts in layout when the fonts swap, which can be undesirable.

You could opt for `font-display: fallback`, which attempts to account for this by hiding any text on screen for the first 100ms, optimistically hoping that your font downloads in that time frame.

If your font downloads within the first 100ms, it gets applied to the first visible text shown to the user (no FOUT).

If not, at 100ms the text gets rendered with the fallback typeface and the same pattern as `font-display: swap` resumes with your font getting swapped in once it eventually downloads.